# change format of X axis in c3.js chart

Tags: javascript, c3.js

I am generating a c3.js chart with the folling JSON and code, I'm trying to change the format of the X axis dates like this "November 2016" "N16". Can I get some help with this please? Thanks!

```
    response = [["November 2016","December 2016","January 2017","February 2017","March 2017","April 2017"],["total"
    ,2,43,60,51,46,110],["mammo",1,20,34,12,12,60],["face",1,20,16,30,32,32],["body",0,3,10,9,2,18],["photo"
    ,0,19,27,12,5,21],["scan",2,24,33,39,41,89]]
    initMonthlyUsageChart(response);

function initMonthlyUsageChart(amounts) {
  var months = amounts.shift();
  c3.generate({
    bindto: '#monthly_usage_chart-js',
    data: { columns : amounts },
    axis: {
      x: {
        type: 'category',
        categories: months,
        tick: {
          rotate: 90,
          format: function (x) { // x comes in as a time string.
                x[0] = x[0].map(function(date) {
                  return date.replace(/^(\w{1}).*(\d{2})$/gi, "$1$2");
                });
            }
        }
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Please share your whole code
and what is in "months variable"
share via jsfiddle so i can try to get solution as per you required

Comment: @KaushikAndani ok I updated the code thanks!

Comment: your chart is not generated its give me error
please give me proper code of chart

Answer (score 0):

x doesn't come in as a time string, it comes in as an index to the category

Therefore, change to this bit of code to do what you need:

```
      format: function (x) { // x comes in as an index
        return months[x].replace(/^(\w{1}).*(\d{2})$/gi, "$1$2");
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach may helps to format categorical chart tick formatting :

```
var config = bindto: '#monthly_usage_chart-js',
    data: { columns : amounts },
    axis: {
      x: {
        type: 'category',
        categories: months,
        tick: {
          rotate: 90,
          format: function (x) { // x comes in as a time string.
                x[0] = x[0].map(function(date) {
                  return date.replace(/^(\w{1}).*(\d{2})$/gi, "$1$2");
                });
            }
        }
      }
    };

    config.axis.x.tick = {
        format : function(x) {
            var desiredValue = config.axis.x.categories[x];//'cause x here is a key for category chart
            return desiredValue.replace(/^(\w{1}).*(\d{2})$/gi, "$1$2");//apply your formatting stuff
        }
    };

    var chart = c3.generate(config);
```